# bitwise NOT on const byte fields in C#

Tags: c#

I realized that if I have a field or variable of type 'byte', I can apply bitwise NOT(~) on it and cast it to byte. However, if the field is 'const byte', I can still apply bitwise NOT(~), but I cannot cast it to byte. For example,

This compiles:

```
class Program
{
    byte b = 7;
    void Method()
    {
        byte bb = (byte) ~b;
    }
}
```

But this has a compile error ("Constant value '-8' cannot be converted to a 'byte' "):

```
class Program
{
    const byte b = 7;
    void Method()
    {
        byte bb = (byte) ~b;
    }
}
```

I wonder why?

Comment: In the first case variable is not const, so bitwise will be perfromed at runtime - then you will get the exception. I suppose that in the second case, compiler wants to replace that value with bitwised one at compile time (because b is `const` so its value won't change - so why waste resources at runtime?) so it gives compile-time error.

Comment: @pwas you will not get an exception unless the program is compiled with `/checked`, which is *definitely* not a normal scenario.

Comment: @280Z28 you are right, by default `/checked` is off.

Answer (score 4):

Because the `~` operator is only predefined for `int`, `uint`, `long`, and `ulong`.  Your first sample implicitly casts `b` to an `int`, performs the negation, then explicitly casts back to a byte.

In the second example, `b` is a constant, so the compiler is also inlining the negation, effectively making a constant `int` with a value of -8 (the signed twos-complement of 7).  And since a constant negative value can't be cast to a `byte` (without adding an `unchecked` context), you get a compilation error.

To avoid the error just store the result in a non-constant `int` variable:

```
const byte b = 7;

void Main()
{
    int i = ~b;
    byte bb = (byte)i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `~` operator defined for `byte`.  It's defined for `int`.  The `byte` is implicitly converted to an `int`, and that `int` is NOT-ed.  That resulting `int` is not in the range of a `byte` (0 - 255, inclusive), so it can only be converted to a `byte` at compile-time via an unchecked cast:

```
byte bb = unchecked((byte)~b);
```

The second program doesn't compile because, due to the use of compile time constants, it's able to validate the improper conversion at compile time.  The compiler cannot make this assertion with non-compile time constant values.

Comment: But that doesn't explained the difference between `const` and non-`const`. and the first program does compile and run without problem, resulting in the value 248 (the inverse of 7)

Comment: @NathanA It would seem that the compiler specs for valid `byte` constants differ from the valid integer values that can be explicitly converted to a `byte` (something outside of the language specs entirely).

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain the difference, but the simple solution for your second program is to mark it unchecked like so:

```
byte bb = unchecked((byte)~b);
```